# Code not working after redux function in axios call

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I'm having trouble with redux/axios. I want to change the store after an axios request is successful, and after the store change, I want to change the application state. I expected the code to get to my function but that does not happen, and I'm not sure why! Is redux async? if so how can I make a sync call? (Left some code bellow)

```
        axios.post(url,{
            "system":system,
        })
        .then(res => {
          this.props.setTest(res) #code does not follow this line, no state is set
          this.setState({
            test_data:res,
            redirect:true
          })
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
          if(error.response){
              if(error.response.data["Error"]){
                  console.log("There was an error fetching the test")
              }
          }
      })
```

```
export function setTest(test){
    return {type: "SET_TEST",payload: test}
}
```

```
case "SET_TEST":{
            console.log("SET_TEST")
            return {
                ...state,

                (and other changed args)
            };
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very likely that `this.props.setTest(res)`  triggers some kind of error.

Since later you have a `catch` block where you only handle very specific error, that error makes it never out and you will never know what the error was in the first place until you console.log it.
So:

```js
.catch((error)=>{
    if(error.response && error.response.data["Error"]){
       console.log("There was an error fetching the test")
    } else {
       // don't swallow your error, log it!
       console.log("some unexpected error happened:", error);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! It was indeed and error but since nothing has printing I did't know

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understood how Redux works. In your case, setTest returns an action. An action needs to be **dispatched**.

Try this:

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
```

// inside your component

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
dispatch(setTest(res));
```